# i wanted to create file with name with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to create a empty file with the present datetime as it's name
this is the respected code:

```
import datetime
 filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()

 def create_file():
     with open(filename1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".txt",'w') as file:
         file.write("")

create_file()
```

i am getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\DIPU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36> .\python timedate.py
  File "timedate.py", line 3
    filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

pls, help me to remove this error n pls tell me the solution as well

Comment: remove the space before `def create_file():`

Comment: and also before `filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: This is an `IndentationError`, and whenever you see that, you should check your indentation/format. If you're not sure about the indentation rules, there're many tutorials you can look at on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is sensitive to white space (spaces and tabs) and some lines of your code has white space where it doesn't belong. Make sure you take that out of line 3. Only the contents of that function `create_file()` should be indented.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains extra spaces before several lines causing the error. Remove those spaces.
Try running this code.

```
import datetime
filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()

def create_file():
    with open(filename1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".txt",'w') as file:
        file.write("")

create_file()
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a space in the line `filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()` and `def create_file()`

```
import datetime
filename1 =datetime.datetime.now()

def create_file():
     with open(filename1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".txt",'w') as file:
         file.write("")

create_file()
```